# Creating a new sheet based off of 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have successfully come up with creating a new sheet based off of the dates column, however when I try to make it more specific by adding the location it doesn't seem to work. It runs fine, without error, but it just returns the same data as when is was just specified by dates, any feedback would be helpful!

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PromptUserForInputDates()

Dim strStart As String, strEnd As String, strPromptMessage As String
Dim LastOccupiedRowNum As String, LastOccupiedColNum As String
Dim strLocation As String

strStart = InputBox("Please enter the start date")

If Not IsDate(strStart) Then
    strPromptMessage = "Not Valid Date"

    MsgBox strPromptMessage

    Exit Sub
 End If

 strEnd = InputBox("Please enter the end date")

 If Not IsDate(strStart) Then
   strPromptMessage = "Not Valid Date"

   MsgBox strPromptMessage

   Exit Sub
End If

Call PromptUserForLocation
Call CreateSubsetWorksheet(strStart, strEnd, strLocation)

End Sub

Public Sub PromptUserForLocation()

Dim strLocation As String, strPromptMessage As String

strLocation = InputBox("Please Enter the Location")

Exit Sub
End Sub

Public Sub CreateSubsetWorksheet(StartDate As String, EndDate As String, Location As String)

Dim wksData As Worksheet, wksTarget As Worksheet
Dim lngLastRow As Long, lngLastCol As Long, lngDateCol As Long
Dim rngFull As Range, rngResult As Range, rngTarget As Range
Dim lngLocationCol As Long

Set wksData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lngDateCol = 4
lngLocationCol = 21

lngLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksData)
lngLastCol = LastOccupiedColNum(wksData)
With wksData
    Set rngFull = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lngLastRow, lngLastCol))
End With

With rngFull
    .AutoFilter Field:=lngDateCol, _
                Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, _
                Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate _

  With rngFull
    .AutoFilter Field:=lngLocationCol, _
                Criteria1:=Location

     If wksData.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells                   (xlCellTypeVisible).Count = 1 Then

        MsgBox "Dates Filter out all data"

        wksData.AutoFilterMode = False
        If wksData.FilterMode = True Then
            wksData.ShowAllData
        End If
        Exit Sub

    Else

        Set rngResult = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        Set wksTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        Set rngTarget = wksTarget.Cells(1, 1)
        rngResult.Copy Destination:=rngTarget
    End If
  End With
End With
wksData.AutoFilterMode = False
If wksData.FilterMode = True Then
    wksData.ShowAllData
End If

MsgBox "Data Transferred"

End Sub

Public Function LastOccupiedRowNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long

Dim lng As Long
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
    With Sheet
        lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    End With
Else
    lng = 1
End If
LastOccupiedRowNum = lng
End Function

Public Function LastOccupiedColNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long

Dim lng As Long
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
    With Sheet
        lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    End With
Else
    lng = 1
End If
LastOccupiedColNum = lng

End Function
```

Comment: you may want to give more details (examples) about your issue and narrow down the code excerpt concerning it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `strLocation` is not passed from the `Public Sub PromptUserForLocation()` back to the `Public Sub PromptUserForInputDates()`.

A easy solution is to just add the `strLocations` `InputBox` code into the `Public Sub PromptUserForInputDates()`.

Just replace your `Public Sub PromptUserForInputDates()` with the following:

I also added an example for the `Date` format to be included in the `Inputbox`, this will help users input correct data for Excel to process.

```
Public Sub PromptUserForInputDates()

    Dim strStart As String, strEnd As String, strPromptMessage As String
    Dim LastOccupiedRowNum As String, LastOccupiedColNum As String
    Dim strLocation As String

    strStart = InputBox("Please enter the start date" & _
                        vbCr & _
                        vbCr & _
                        "Example: 2016/01/01")

    If Not IsDate(strStart) Then
        strPromptMessage = "Not Valid Date"
        MsgBox strPromptMessage
        Exit Sub
    End If

    strEnd = InputBox("Please enter the end date" & _
                      vbCr & _
                      vbCr & _
                      "Example: 2016/01/10")

    If Not IsDate(strStart) Then
        strPromptMessage = "Not Valid Date"
        MsgBox strPromptMessage
        Exit Sub
    End If

    strLocation = InputBox("Please Enter the Location")

    If strLocation = Empty Then
        strPromptMessage = "Please enter a location."
        MsgBox strPromptMessage
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Call CreateSubsetWorksheet(strStart, strEnd, strLocation)

End Sub
```